# Exit main sub procedure if called sub is false

Tags: vba, excel

I have a 'protection' sub procedure `Sub unprot_manually()` which can been seen below. I have another sub procedure which could be refereed to as the main procedure of the workbook. I would like to call this protection procedure prior to allowing the user to run the main procedure. With my current code below, the user is able to run the main procedure regardless of entering the correct password. Do I need to create a 'protection' function, define as Boolean, and then pass as a parameter to the main sub?

```
Sub unprot_manually()
Dim password_input
Dim Pass As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Pass = "xxxxxx"
password_input = Application.InputBox("Password", "Awaiting User Input..")

If password_input = Pass Then
    Call Unprot
'Else
'MsgBox ("Incorrect, Good Bye")
'MsgBox ("Incorrect")
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Just so we're clear, `Unprot` would be the "main procedure" you're referring to?

Comment: No `Prot` and "Unprot' are two separate sub procedures which are intended to influence the execution of the third `main` sub procedure

Answer (score 0):

change it from a Sub to a Function, and then check the return value.

e.g. in your main procedure,

```
if unprot_manually then
    rest of program
else
    msgbox "Incorrect Passowrd"
end if
```

your other section would then become:

```
Function  unprot_manually() as Boolean
'set to fail condition until we get a success status
unprot_manually=False

...

If password_input = Pass Then
    Call Unprot
    'passed, so set success condition
    unpot_manually=True
End If

...

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a UDF to do a simple string comparison is a bit OTT. You don't even need a separate procedure for this, just put the If block in your main procedure

```
Sub Unprot()
   If Application.InputBox("Password", "Awaiting User Input..") = "xxxxxx" Then
      ' Rest of code here
   Else
      MsgBox "Incorrect Password!"
   End If
End Sub
```

Even better than this, just set the worksheet protection with the `UserInterfaceOnly` option set to true, then the user can't make any changes on the front end, but your code can still run without obstruction.

---

**UPDATE:** (In response to comment)

Just use a variable and check the input:

```
Sub Unprot()
    Dim tempStr As String
    tempStr = InputBox("Password", "Awaiting User Input..") ' Assign value via input
        If tempStr = vbNullString Then Exit Sub 'If no input, exit sub

    If tempStr = "xxxxxx" Then
      'Rest of Code
    Else
      MsgBox "Incorrect Password!"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What about if the user clicks `cancel` how could the code be edited to exit without `MsgBox "Incorrect Password!"` as no password was literally entered by the user.